# Two M/M/1 queues working independently

Tags: queuing-theory

If two M/M/1 queues with arrival rate $\lambda$ and service rate $\mu$ are working independently. Is the system equivalent to a single M/M/1 queue with arrival rate $2\lambda$ and service rate $2\mu$?

Comment: What happens when the first customer arrives?  Does that customer get served twice as fast?

Comment: Another hint: In both scenarios, think about what it takes for a server to be idle.